# Kivy function as a property

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am working on a big GUI and inside the GUI, I might have the following Widget more often:

[image]

Therefor, I've made the following kivy class:

```
<ParameterFileInput@ParameterInput>
    ParameterLabel:
        width: root.label_width
        text: root.label_text
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: None, 1.0
        width: 10
    ParameterTextInput:
        gid: root.content_id
        on_text_validate: app.set_widget_content(self.gid, None)

        size_hint: 0.7,1.0
        text: root.preset_text
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: None, 1.0
        width: 10
    Button:
        text: "Browse"
        size_hint: None, 1.0
        on_press: root.button_function
        width: 100
```

and in python:

```
class ParameterInput(StackLayout):
    content_id = StringProperty()
    label_text = StringProperty()
    preset_text = StringProperty()
    label_width = NumericProperty(80)
    spinner_width = NumericProperty(100)
    spinner_values = ListProperty()
    button_function = ObjectProperty()
```

The thing is the button_function that should be called when I hit the button.
On example of my implementation is the following:

```
ParameterFileInput:
    label_text: "data_file"
    content_id: "data_file"
    button_function: app.train_button()
```

Probably needless to say that `app.train_button()` is not called.

I would be very happy if someone could help me with this.

Greetings, Finn

Comment: Well, what is a function then?

Comment: try with:`on_press: root.button_function()`

Comment: Yeah I just tried that and it works for me too :) Thank you!!

Comment: If you publish a response, would you mark it as correct?

Comment: An additional question.
Could I define a lambda expression in the kv file? 
So instead of button_function: app.train_button
I would write a lambda expression?

Comment: Yes I would :).

Comment: If you realize you have to invoke the function to make it work, so you could use the lambda but you would have to invoke it, for example: `(lambda: print("test"))()`, but I see that it makes your code less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the bind in python you pass the name of the function, internally kivy makes the invocation of the function, in the case of the kivy does not, so you must make the invocation, in your case the solution is:

```
on_press: root.button_function()
```